# Calculate value in go with decimal part

Tags: go

I'm currently working in a little porgram that calculates a formula for some numbers entered, the fact is I need the answer with some decimal values, but I've been unable to find a way to print my answer as a double or other similar type of variable with the information on the internet, it either produce an error or only prints the integer part of the answer.

```
func main() {

var m = 0
a := make([]int, 5)


   for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
      fmt.Scan(&a[i])
    }

  m = a[0]*60 + a[2] + (a[4]/60)
  fmt.Println(m)

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division truncates the result towards zero. Use a floating-point result. For example, with minimal loss of accuracy,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var m float64
    a := make([]int64, 5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        _, err := fmt.Scan(&a[i])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            i--
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
    m = float64((a[0]*60+a[2])*60+a[4]) / 60
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5 6
[2 3 4 5 6]
124.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a `float64` rather than an `int` if you're looking to use decimal places with numbers. Just be careful using them with currency.

Answer (score 0):

use fmt.Printf function link C - printf function

```
import fmt
value := 2.2
fmt.Printf("%f", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float64, and convert all your ints into floats *before* calculations.

The following will give you decimal values.

```
m = float64(a[0])*60 + float64(a[2]) + (float64(a[4])/60)
```

But this will give ints.

```
m = float64(a[0]*60 + a[2] + (a[4]/60))
```